# how to declare an array of ObservableArrayList Java

Tags: java, javafx

If I have an observableList data1 =     FXCollections.observableArrayList();

I want to stick it in an array because I have a bunch of them. 
Can I do that ?
If yes, whats the syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` interface provides a method called `toArray()` to convert a list to array. This should do:

```
data1.toArray();
```

**EDIT**

As per the questioner input, you may need this:

```
observableList[] observableListArray = new observableList[SIZE_YOU_NEED];
observableListArray[index] = data1;
```

Comment: @user4552859 If it helped then please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark left to my answer. Accepting an answer helps other facing the same challenge.

Comment: Note that if you do things this way, you can't properly type the `ObservableList`, as you can't create an array of generic types. In other words, you should really be doing something like `ObservableList<String> data1 = ... ;` for a single list, and you can't do `ObservableList<String>[] observableListArray = new ObservableList<String>[n]`; You should probably consider something like `List<ObservableList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();` (i.e. use a list of these instead of an array).